# How to pass arguments to a script that auto run as administrator?

Tags: vbscript, elevated-privileges

How do I pass arguments to a script that auto run as administrator?

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1 Then
  Command1 = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
End If

If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") = False Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
    WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo Command1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the arguments to the argument list you already have (`/elevated`):

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1 Then
  Command1 = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
End If

If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") = False Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
    WScript.ScriptFullName & """ " & Command1 & " /elevated", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo Command1
```